# Java basic loop

Tags: java, loops

I have no idea why my second for loop won't execute.. It compiles but when I run this it does not work ~_~

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ranges
{


 public static void main (String[] args)

  {

 Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

       int size;
       int input;
       int count = 0;
       int occurence = 0;
       System.out.print ("Please enter the size of your array: ");
       size = scan.nextInt();
       int[] list = new int[size];



       for (int index = 0 ; index < list.length ; index++)
       {
           System.out.print ("Please enter an integer between 0 to 50: ");
           input = scan.nextInt();

           if ( input >= 0 && input <= 50 )
           {
               list[index] = input;
            }
           else
           {
               System.out.println ("Invalid output, please try again");
               index--;
           }
        }




       int right = (list.length)-1;
       int left = 0;

        for (int counter = left ; counter < list.length ; counter++)
        {
            while ( right >= left )
            {
                if ( list[left] == list[right] )
                {
                    occurence++;
                    right--;
                }
            }
           right = (list.length)-1;
           System.out.println ("The number " + list[left] + " was added " + occurence + "4 times");
        }

         for (int value : list)
        {
            System.out.print (value + " ");
        }
       ;








    }
}
```

My updated for loop to evaulate occurences

> for (int left = 0 ; left < list.length ; left++)
>
> {

```
        while ( right >= left )
        {
            if ( list[left] == list[right] )
            {
                occurence++;

            }
            right--;
        }


       System.out.println ("The number " + list[left] + " was added " + occurence + " times");
       right = (list.length)-1;
       occurence = 0;
    }
```

I have cleaned it up a bit, and now occurences are same as the inputs

Comment: "It compiles but when I run this it does not work ~_~" - well what happens? do you get an exception?

Comment: @Mihai Stancu: The homework tag was declared obsolete!

Comment: @MihaiStancu no, homework tag must not be used.

Comment: Good comments above, and answers below. One additional comment: It's almost always a bad idea to modify the loop variable inside the loop. It may work, but don't get into the habit of doing it. Find another way to structure you code so that you don't have to do that. If I were the instructor, I'd fail you for that, regardless of whether the program worked.

Comment: This is not homework guys >_<

Comment: @Philipp and Alfabravo - my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You second `for` is also working. The problem is in `while` loop condition i.e. `while ( right >= left )`. If `list[left] == list[right]` is not equal, it goes in infinite loop as neigther `right` nor `left` changing in that case.

I think, you need to change your `while` as  below(move `right--` outside the `if` condition):

```
  while ( right >= left )
   {
     if ( list[left] == list[right] )
      {
        occurence++;
      }
      right--;
    }
```

Two more issues:

Please **re-initialize** `occurence =0;` before the while loop so that it counts occurence of each number and remove `4` from your `System.out.println()` e.g. below:

```
for (int counter = left ; counter < list.length ; counter++)
{ 
  occurence = 0; //< initialize to 0
  while ( right >= left )
  {
      if ( list[left] == list[right] )
      {
         occurence++;
       }
           right--;
   }
   right = (list.length)-1;
       //remove 4 after "occurance +"
   System.out.println ("The number " + list[left] + 
                                            " was added " + occurence + " times");
 }
```

EDIT: working sample with HashMap:

```
       Map<Integer, Integer> scannedNums = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
        for (int counter = left ; counter < list.length ; counter++)
        {
            if(scannedNums.get(list[counter]) == null){
                scannedNums.put(list[counter], 1);
            }else{
                int currentCount = scannedNums.get(list[counter]);
                scannedNums.put(list[counter], currentCount+1);
            }
        }

        Set<Integer> nums = scannedNums.keySet();
        Iterator<Integer> numIter = nums.iterator();
        while(numIter.hasNext()){
            int number = numIter.next();
            System.out.println ("The number " + number + 
                    " was added " + scannedNums.get(number) + " times");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry about that. But it does not give correct number of occurences in the array, is there something wrong in my formula>?

Comment: @Aaron: There are two more issues. Please look at the updated answer.

Comment: Occurence variable is already initialized to 0 and I have removed the 4

Comment: @Aaron: You need to reinitilize within `for` loop otherwise it will keep counting number one occurence with number 2 and so on which you won't want. Through `occurance` you are trying to count occurance of each number, right?

Comment: Ok thank you, it's sort of working but it will check again for the same number, for example, if i enter size 5 array with 1,1,1,2,3 the first output is correct but second one will say 1  has been entered twice and third output will say 1 has been entered once.

Comment: @Aaron: You need to keep track of numbers scanned prior and add a condition before `while` loop. If you need help, please let me know. You may keep the track using `List` or `String` for simplicity. Which one you like better?

Comment: How do i keep track using list?

Comment: @Aaron Keep adding the scanned numbers in the list and use `contains` to check, if they are already scanned. Or better to use `HashMap` to maintain the unique number and their count.

Comment: @Aaron: I added a working sample in the answer, please check and let me know, if you need explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick look, and suggestion for the future.

This code:

```
  while ( right >= left )
    {
        if ( list[left] == list[right] )
        {
            occurence++;
            right--;
        }
    }
```

suggests that if list[left] != list[right], yet right is still >= left, this loop will never stop.  You might want to move the right-- OUTSIDE of the if statement, if all you want is a count of how many occurrences are found.

Finally, when you say "the loop doesn't work", that's a little less than helpful.  Perhaps showing your output, or the WAY in which it doesn't work would be better.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working properly but looks like the formula is wrong. I'm trying to get how many occurences of the same number the user has entered in the array. Do i have the correct formula?

Comment: SHOW YOUR TEST.   It's SO much easier to debug someone else's code when they actually bother to tell you what it's really doing.

Comment: If I entered 10,30,10,20,30...  I'd expect it to say "2 of 10, 2 of 30, 1 of 10, 1 of 20, and 1 of 30"... according to what you have.  Maybe you should look up the idea of a Map to store the values and how many times they were typed in.

Comment: Our class has not covered that concept yet. This is just one question out of the textbook for practice. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

What error does it give?

One immediate problem I see is that if there are no occurrences, the while loop will run for ever. Also the first for loop could give index out of bounds.

For the first loop, instead of:

```
    for (int index = 0 ; index < list.length ; index++)
   {
       System.out.print ("Please enter an integer between 0 to 50: ");
       input = scan.nextInt();

       if ( input >= 0 && input <= 50 )
       {
           list[index] = input;
        }
       else
       {
           System.out.println ("Invalid output, please try again");
           index--;
       }
    }
```

I would do:

```
    for (int index = 0 ; index < list.length ; ++index)
    {
         while(true)
         {
             System.out.print ("Please enter an integer between 0 to 50: ");
             input = scan.nextInt();
             if ( input >= 0 && input <= 50 )
             {
                list[index] = input;
                break;
             }
             System.out.println ("Invalid output, please try again");
         }
     }
```

And for the second loop:

```
    for (int counter = left ; counter < list.length ; counter++)
    {
        occurence = 0;
        for( int i = counter; i <= right; ++i)
        {
            if( list[left] == list[i] )
                 ++occurence;
        }
       System.out.println ("The number " + list[left] + " was added " + occurence + " times");
    }
```